# Map one array to another Typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I have 2 arrays that has different Models

here is model of first array

```
export class TenancyTenantDto  {
name!: string | undefined;
email!: string | undefined;
paymentMethodName!: string | undefined;
paymentMethodId!: number | undefined;
propertyTenantId!: number | undefined;
isPrimary!: boolean | undefined;
id!: number | undefined;
}
```

and second array model

```
 export class TenancyTenantViewModel {
    name: string;
    email: string;
    paymentMethodName: string;
    paymentMethodId: number;
    tenancyTenantId: number;
    tenantId: number;
    isPrimary: boolean;
    id: Guid;


}
```

I need to map 1 array to 2. How I can do it?

I tried to do it like this `this.tenants = [...tenants.map(e => new TenancyTenantViewModel({id: e.id, etc.}))];`

but seems it not works.

Comment: in es6 I would do ```this.tenants = tenants.map( ({id, ...etc}) => Object.assign(new TenancyTenantViewModel(), {id, ...etc}))```

Answer (score 1):

Define your map:

```
function mapType(source: TenancyTenantDto): TenancyTenantViewModel {
     return { // Your mapping logic here }
}
```

Usage:

```
const originalArray: TenancyTenantDto[] = [...]
const mappedArray: TenancyTenantViewModel[] = originalArray.map(mapType);
```